# counting total numbers of div with jquery

Tags: jquery

how can i count the total number of divs with same name.......i.e.

suppose i have 3 divs with same name than how can i count these three divs with jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by name? There is no `name` attribute defined for `div` elements (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-DIV).

Comment: What is the relevance of the name? You accepted an answer that doesn't consider the name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives total number of `<div>` elements on the page:

```
var count = $('div').length
```

Comment: That doesn't count the number of div elements with a certain name, it counts ALL div elements.

Comment: Yes, but what does "with a certain name" mean? Divs cannot have a name attribute.

Comment: @Andreas: lenght is not a function, is a property. Look at the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var cnt = $('div[name=asfd]').length;
```

However, the name property is not a standard attribute for the div element.

If you are looking for a text inside the div elements:

```
var cnt = $('div').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == 'John Doe'
}).length;
```

You can do any comparison you like in the filter. Note that this will check *all* div elements in the document, so you should try to limit the number of elements in the first expression if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy +)

```
$('div').size()
```

Or specify any additional selector parameters.